# Changing Image with Radio Buttons and JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently stuck in trying to render different images in the user's view based of radio button selection. I'm able to manipulate the image if I hard code selections, but I cannot find how to pass the user's selection from JQuery to Rails.

First my view with the radio buttons is like so:

```
<!-- VIEW CODE -->
<% [ 'credit_32.png', 'credit_64.png' ].each do |image| %>
          <%= radio_button_tag 'image', image, @image == image, :class => 'image' %><%= image_tag(image)%>
    <% end %>
```

I then have a div that I'm trying to update with either of the images based off selection, my function to change, in a javascript file I listen for this on the click event:

```
// Javascript Asset File
    $(function() {
        $("input.image").live("click", function() {
            $image = ($(this).val());
            $.getScript( this.href );
        });
    });
```

This sets the user's selection to the $image variable, and calls the index.js.erb code which will then rerender a partial.

```
// Index.js.erb for responding to
    $("div#button").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@button)) %>");
```

The problem I'm having is how do I get my previous variable to my partial?

```
<!-- Partial Code -->
    <% if @button_image = $image %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(@button_image), button_path(button, :only_path => false), :target => '_blank' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag('credit_32.png'), button_path(button, :only_path => false), :target => '_blank' %>
    <% end %>
```

If I could set this @button_image instance variable to my JQuery $image object, I'd be good, though I do not know if this is possible? Could I possibly save the JQuery object into a session and use it here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `$.getScript()` method is only a shorthand for the `$.ajax()` method (link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

you could just use the normal `$.ajax()` method with a `data` attribute. eg:

```
$.ajax({  
  url: this.href,  
  dataType: "script",  
  data: { image: $(this).val() }  
});
```

now in rails you can access it with the `params` hash.

more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/